# Why is my code only printing x and y once?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to be able to move the turtle to my mouse click than print x and y.

```
import turtle

tim = turtle.Turtle()
tim.shape('turtle')
screen = tim.getscreen()

def getPos():
# this should move turtle to mouse click and print coords
    screen.onscreenclick(tim.goto)
    print(tim.xcor(), tim.ycor())

def main():
# once I run, it prints coords but once I move turtle it does not
    getPos()
    screen.mainloop()
    turtle.bye()
    
main()
```

Once I run my program, it prints x and y. However, once I move the turtle with a mouse click, it does not print the coordinates.

Comment: You only call `getPos` once. Why would the print happen more than once?

Comment: Do you expect that something else will call `getPos()`?

Comment: This is why I am confused. I am under the impression that getPos() is called more than once because of screen.mainloop(). Even though I only call it once, why does screen.oncscreenclick(tim.goto) still work?

Answer (score 0):

You've completely misunderstood how screen click events work in Python turtle.  When it comes to event handing, you need to review the documentation, you can't simply go by function names.

You don't ask for a click, instead you register a function that will be called if/when the user clicks:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def gotoPos(x, y):
    tim.setheading(tim.towards(x, y))
    tim.goto(x, y)
    print(x, y)

tim = Turtle()
tim.shape('turtle')

screen = Screen()
screen.onscreenclick(gotoPos)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Thank you so much. I am fairly new to Turtle so I was confused when reading the documentation. Thanks again.